Multiprocessing with gramformer
I am trying to implement multiprocessing with gramformer which is an open source model to correct grammatical errors. I have tried several approaches but i keep getting errors cant be pickled. i am also using spacy which seems to have no problem with multiprocessing.
my main goal is to try to implement this in a class. i have tried creating seperate functions but even that does not work
class GramformerWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize Gramformer
        self.gf = Gramformer(models=1, use_gpu=False)

    def process_entries(self,entry):
        paragraph=spacy_wrapper.nlp(entry)
        corrected_entry=entry=''
        for sentence in paragraph.sents:
            corrected_sentence = list(self.gf.correct(sentence.text))[0]
            print(corrected_sentence)
            if not sentence.text.endswith('.') and corrected_sentence.endswith('.'):
                corrected_sentence = corrected_sentence[:-1]
            corrected_entry=corrected_entry+' '+corrected_sentence
        return corrected_entry

    def correct_sentences(self, lst):
        length_of_lst=len(lst)
        part=int(length_of_lst/8)+1
        first_index=0
        last_index=part
        processes=[]
        for _ in range(8):
            lst_part=lst[first_index:last_index]
            p=multiprocessing.Process(target=self.process_entries,args=lst_part)
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
            first_index+=part
            last_index+=part

        for process in processes:
            process.join()
        
        return corrected_entries

class SpacyWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

gramformer_wrapper = GramformerWrapper()
spacy_wrapper=SpacyWrapper()


argsargument in multiprocessing.Process() takes a tuple. Make sure you are passing either a tuple with a single argument or (arg,). Make also sure you shield the subprocess import with the if __name__ == '__main__': construct

I understand now the lst that i am passing should be passed actually as a tuple like (lst_part,) also i tried using this with main block but i still recieve the same error. the main problem lies with the function process_entries not getting pickled
